# How to attach a note to a specific date in a dynamic graph in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a graph that I update every month with new data. I want to annotate some comments to relevant days inside the graph, and when I update it, they stay fixed to that days.

Now, I draw this notes inside the graph and when I update it, they lose their position.

Comment: Check out this [video](http://www.datapigtechnologies.com/flashfiles/deltachart.html). It's long (6 minutes), but it may give you some ideas how to place comments dynamically. I did not try it because I don't know how your data/graph is laid out, so I couldn't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use data labels:

1. Single left-click the data series of interest.
2. Single left-click the data point of interest.
3. Right-click; select 'Add Data Label'
4. Single left-click the new data label three times until a cursor appears.

You can now enter text into the data label and it should remain attached to the chart data point.